# Copying data from one attribute to another with Python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, qgis-python-console, syntaxerror

I'm trying to update an attribute in a layer in QGIS with data from a joined field in the same layer. I have looked at a few different instructions and tutorials, but for some reason I can't get all the way there. I'm quite the novice when it comes to Python.

This is what I type:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
Provtyp = layer.fields().indexFromName('Provtyp')
WFS_update_Provtyp = layer.fields().indexFromName('WFS_update_Provtyp')
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), Provtyp, feat.attributes()[WFS_update_Provtyp])
layer.commitChanges()
```

and this is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 178, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 106, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 93, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 143, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, True)
  File "<input>", line 3
    layer.commitChanges()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question so that the error text is in the Question body *as text*. Image are not legible on all devices, and can't be searched by others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute it from a script. It should work.

If you want to do it in the console, you need to fire the Enter after the For-Loop.